# Redis Template hash key with expiration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I have

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(key, hashKey, value);
```

I need to set key and hash key expire value, and each hash key has expired value, here is the expire for just key

`redisTemplate.expire(key, timeout, unit)`

Comment: that's not supported

Comment: To add to what @sonus21 said, setting a TTL on the hashmap is allowed, but setting TTL on the keys inside the hashmap is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc of [redis](https://redis.io/commands/expire), you can expire the whole hash, but not a single key-value pair in it.

Possible ways:

1. Break your hash into keys. Say, your hash has key `myhash` and sub-key and value like `{apple: foo, banana: bar}`. Then just instead create key `myhash_apple` with value `foo`, and `myhash_banana` with value `bar`.
2. Manually expire things. Use your code to periodically (say, at midnight) scan those hashs, and remove those outdated.